# How can I test 50 threads and 60 threads ,for slave 1 and slave 2 respectively from jmeter non gui command?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Scenario :
I have 2 slave machines configured , I want to send 50 users for slave 1, 60 users for slave 2 . I am using non GUI jmeter from command .

> IP Address example :

```
Slave 1 : 1.0.0.1

Slave 2 : 2.0.0.2
```

**Jmeter test plan configuration variables:**

Number of threads :`${__P(threads1,)}`

Ramp-up period : `${__P(threads2,)}`

Loop Count : `${__P(threads3,)}`

I tried following command on jmeter start, but its not working as per expected:

**jmeter -n -t POC1.jmx -R 1.0.0.1,2.0.0.2 -Gthreads1=50 -Gthreads2=1 -Gthreads3=1, -Gthreads1=60 -Gthreads2=1 -Gthreads3=1**

Please help me if I am wrong in above command , please tell me how can I send 50 user threads , ramp up period 1 and loop count 1 for slave 1 and 60 user threads ramp up period 1 and loop count 1 for slave 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do it the above way as:

1. All remote slaves are executing **the same** test plan
2. You can pass **global** properties via `-G` command-line argument, so all the remote clients will be having the same properties set

The solution is to use different *user.properties* on different slaves, like:

1. Define amount of virtual users in your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) using [__P() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

   ```
   ${__P(threads,)}
   ```
2. On first slave add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   threads=50
   ```
3. On second slave add the next line to *user.properties* file

   ```
   threads=60
   ```
4. Restart JMeter on slaves

You can also pass **threads** property value via `-J` command line argument while starting JMeter servers like:

- On first slave

  ```
  jmeter -Jthreads=50 -s -j jmeter-slave1.log .....
  ```
- On second slave

  ```
  jmeter -Jthreads=60 -s -j jmeter-slave2.log .....
  ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on using JMeter properties, setting and overriding them

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T , it worked after specifying command on each slave with threads count  , please can you help me how to specify this thread count in  user.properties , I mean on which line I should specify thread count , please give me example ...

Comment: Just add lines like `threads=50` or `threads=60` as I mentioned above. JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, I did same , added threads1=50,threads2=1,threads3=1in user.properties on each slave ,three varibles for test plan . When I run command   **jmeter -n -t POC1.jmx -R 127.0.0.1,1.0.0.1** , but its not picking the value as expected .Whether I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Remove 1, 2, and 3

Comment: Thank you :)  @Dmitri T , it worked for me . But I want to ramp up period (threads2), loop count(threads3) to be parametrized in user.properties which I was trying like in above comment , is it possible or I am doing something which is practically wrong ?....